# The preposition 'about' before numbers

Tags: prepositions, numbers

Can the preposition 'about' be used before numbers like **one** or **two**?

Example 1:

> It employs **about one** contractual workers in the business.

Can the preposition 'about' be used before a range of numbers like **one to two**?

Example 2:

> It employs **about one to two** contractual workers in the business.

Comment: It would not be idiomatic.  More "normal" to say "employs one or two" or "employs a few".

Comment: 1. "About" is not a preposition here; it's an adverb. 2. I don't know what @HotLicks is talking about; I must use this construction about 3 or 4 times a week

Answer (score 1):

It is odd to say "About one worker".  It would be normal to say "About 100 workers", to mean between 90 and 110 (or more, or less, in context)

If you mean a small but non-specific number use "a few":

> The company employs a few contract workers.

It would be fine to say "about 1 metre" which I would understand to be in the range 0.9—1.1 m (or perhaps a smaller or larger range, in context). But I would not call 2m to be "about 1m".  Similarly, I would not call "2 workers" to be "about 1 worker".  This makes "about 1 worker" a rather odd expression.

Similarly "about fifty to a hundred workers" is fine, but "about one or two" is odd.  Just use "a few" in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

*Can the preposition 'about' be used before numbers like one or two? Example:*

> It employs about one contractual workers in the business.

Yes. Although this is a bit casual for such a business discussion. Colloquially, very common.

---

*Can the preposition 'about' be used before a range of numbers like one to two? Example:*

> It employs about one to two contractual workers in the business.

I would say avoid about here and use **around**, or the like (between-and, from-to). However, in very colloquial informal speech, you could also use about.

Comment: "about one workers" is highly ungrammatical.

Comment: sorry for the grammatical mistake here. I meant "about one worker" and I wanted to learn whether "about" could be used before "one" in this context.